# Interacting with Ethereum smart contracts from Python

Tags: python, ethereum

**What Python Ethereum client is meant for smart contract interaction ?**
(mostly [ERC20 tokens](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/) methods `balanceOf`, `transfer`)

I guess web3.py is older and low level close to JSON RPC.
But newer [Trinity](https://trinity.ethereum.org/) in in alpha.

> The Trinity client is currently in an alpha release stage and is not suitable for mission critical production use cases.

Comment: What is smart contract interaction anyways? Is it the app you are making? You need to do a risk assessment and see what is better for your product. Generally is recommended to go for older but stable software rather then new shiny but unstable one.

Comment: Thanks for general comments, I hope for an answer from those who actually developed using some particular client library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a "client", or run your own "node", you need a library and some API service provider.

Try [Brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [Web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/).

For JSON-RPC API services check [Ethereum nodes](https://ethereumnodes.com/).